# Why is there no double rollover interest for forex trades carried overnight on Thursdays?

Tags: foreign-exchange, interest, rollover

Why is there no double rollover interest for forex trades carried overnight on Thursdays? I have been looking everywhere to find an answer to this question, and finding absolutely nothing. I'd appreciate any insights anyone can offer.

Comment: Can you clarify why you think there should be? Weekends result in triple rollover (three days of interest). What is the scenario where you expect double?

Comment: @nanoman Not the OP, but considering that Wedensday got triple swap due to its settlement falling on Saturday, I'd expect Thursday getting double swap due to its settlement falling on Sunday.

Comment: Can you add some details? What Forex trade and where? I doubt you talk about interbank ON swaps? What currency? Some have Spot t+0, other t+1, and many t+2.

Comment: @AKdemy
I am asking about spot Forex that settles at T+2.

Comment: Ok, and what exactly is the trade? You buy normal spot on Thursday? If so, why should there be any interest rate involved? Would you mind writing in detail what your transaction is and why you think there should be interest, also on what platform. You decided to give away a big bounty but I fell like it's completely unclear what you actually ask.